# How is an IIS7 website redirecting without URL Redirect or URL Rewrite?

Tags: iis-7, redirect

I have a web application that used to have this URL format:

http://example.com/application/lang-code/path/to/page.asp

We have upgraded the app and the URLs look like this:

http://example.com/application/app/path/to/page.aspx?lang=lang-code

What's odd is when I use the old URL format, the system automatically redirects me to the new URL format; but URL Rewrite module and URL Redirection modules are not installed.

Is there something else that would do this rewriting?  The lang-code virtual directory doesn't even exist - so I'm not sure what to do here.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable [Failed Request Tracing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731798%28WS.10%29.aspx) and you should be able to see what's causing the redirect.

Comment: Found the culprit using failed request tracing.  Thanks! (can't upvote until I have 15 reputation; sorry)